# TortoiseSVN 1.7 version doesn't have all-wcprops under .svn folder

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I just update my tortoise client in my windows, I found that it was a file called all-wcprops under .svn folder which contains versioning info for the branches/tag/trunk. but now it is gone. I tried with subclipse to checkout, this file still exist.

Anyone found this problem?

The reason I care this so much is becuase I am using ants to build the project and this build target file name is actually based the version name in this file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The meta-data in the .svn folder is meant for consumption by the svn client and not by your scripts. The problem is that your script / build file is dependent on something that it should not be. Whatever you want, try to get it through, say, the svn command line client, svn libraries etc.